# Help me to split string using RegExp

Tags: c#, regex

please help me this problem.
I want to split "-action=1" to "action" and "1".

```
string pattern = @"^-(\S+)=(\S+)$";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string myText = "-action=1";
string[] result = regex.Split(myText);
```

I don't know why result have length=4.

```
result[0] = ""
result[1] = "action"
result[2] = "1"
result[3] = ""
```

Please help me.

P/S: I am using .NET 2.0.

Thanks.

Hello, I tested with string: @"-destination=C:\Program Files\Release" but it have inaccurate result, I don't understand why result's length = 1. I think because it has a white space in string.

I want to split it to "destination" & "C:\Program Files\Release"

More info: This is my requirement:
-string1=string2 -> split it to: string1 & string2.
In string1 & string2 don't contain characters: '-', '=', but they can contain white space.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I tested with string: @"-destination=C:\Program Files\Release" but it have inaccurate result, I don't understand why result's length = 1. I think because it has a white space in string.

I want to split it to "destination" & "C:\Program Files\Release"

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (updated to add `Regex.Split`):

```
string victim = "-action=1";
string[] stringSplit = victim.Split("-=".ToCharArray());
string[] regexSplit = Regex.Split(victim, "[-=]");
```

**EDIT:** Using your example:

```
string input = @"-destination=C:\Program Files\Release -action=value";
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"-(?<name>\w+)=(?<value>[^=-]*)"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", match.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("\tname  = {0}", match.Groups["name" ].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("\tvalue = {0}", match.Groups["value"].Value);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Of course, this code have issues if your path contains `-` character

Answer (score 5):

Don't use split, just use `Match`, and then get the results from the `Groups` collection by index (index 1 and 2).

```
Match match = regex.Match(myText);
if (!match.Success) {
    // the regex didn't match - you can do error handling here
}
string action = match.Groups[1].Value;
string number = match.Groups[2].Value;
```

Comment: You should never use groups by index in .NET Regex... you can name the groups for a reason. Imagine if someone slightly changed the regex later by adding another set of parenthesis. Then you'd have to change all your indexes everywhere. - Use group names instead.

Comment: I only use indexes for very simple cases, such as this one (just one or two captures, no nested groups, etc.). Otherwise, I agree that using names makes the regex much more robust and easier to understand.

Comment: Hello, I tested with string: @"-destination=C:\Program Files\Release" but it have inaccurate result. I think because it has a white space in string.

I want to split it to "destination" & "C:\Program Files\Release"

Answer (score 3):

In .NET Regex, you can name your groups.

```
string pattern = @"^-(?<MyKey>\S+)=(?<MyValue>\S+)$";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string myText = "-action=1";
```

Then do a "Match" and get the values by your group names.

```
Match theMatch = regex.Match(myText);
if (theMatch.Success)
{
    Console.Write(theMatch.Groups["MyKey"].Value); // This is "action"
    Console.Write(theMatch.Groups["MyValue"].Value); // This is "1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using string.split()?

```
string test = "-action=1";
string[] splitUp = test.Split("-=".ToCharArray());
```

I admit, though that this still gives you possibly more parameters than you'd like to see in the split up array...

```
[0] = ""
[1] = "action"
[2] = "1"
```

Comment: What's wrong? You don't get input validation for free, and it may handle things differently (imagine `-range=1-2`).

Comment: Granted, but with RegEx, you don't get *anything* for free, and as the OP has seen, it is not a trivial task to build the appropriate regex string.  I'm just suggesting a reasonably workable alternative that doesn't rely on knowing the unknown (see OP's edit)

Answer (score 0):

In his talk [Regular Expression Mastery](http://perl.plover.com/yak/regex/), Mark Dominus [attributes](http://perl.plover.com/yak/regex/samples/slide070.html) the following helpful rule to *Learning Perl* author (and [fellow StackOverflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz)) Randal Schwartz:

> - Use capturing or `m//g` [or `regex.Match(...)`] when you know what you want to keep.
> - Use `split` when you know what you want to throw away.